# Filter only the tuple key from a grouped list

Tags: python, python-3.x

Consider I have this grouped list:

```
grouped_list = [
    [
        ('Reading.Int3', {'limits': [3, 7], 'sleep': 20}),
        ('Reading.Int4', {'limits': [8, 20], 'sleep': 20})
    ],
    [
        ('Reading.Int1', {'limits': [8, 10], 'sleep': 50}),
        ('Reading.Int6', {'limits': [80, 100], 'sleep': 50})
    ],
    [
        ('Reading.Int5', {'limits': [20, 30], 'sleep': 80})
    ],
    [
        ('Reading.Int2', {'limits': [1, 5], 'sleep': 90})
    ]
]
```

How can I filter only the keys for each tuple keeping the data grouped? Like this:

```
only_keys = [
    ['Reading.Int3', 'Reading.Int4'],
    ['Reading.Int1', 'Reading.Int6'],
    ['Reading.Int5'],
    ['Reading.Int2']
]
```

What I've tried to do:

```
only_keys = list([(el) for el in item] for item in grouped_list)
```

But the list returns the same way. I appreciate any help!

Comment: `[[subitem[0] for subitem in item] for item in grouped_list]
`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this **list comprehension**:

```
only_keys = [[i[0] for i in lst] for lst in grouped_list]
```

`only_keys`:

```
[['Reading.Int3', 'Reading.Int4'], ['Reading.Int1', 'Reading.Int6'], ['Reading.Int5'], ['Reading.Int2']]
```

Answer (score 1):

use list comprehension

```py
# change this
# only_keys = list([(el) for el in item] for item in grouped_list)
# to:

only_keys = [ [el[0] for el in item] for item in grouped_list ]
```